# Reading Irish birthplace on 1851 Wales Census?

Tags: census-records, palaeography, wales, ireland, birthplace

I am looking for help reading the word after Dublin Ireland on the third line down (Christopher Brangham) in the Where Born section.

I think this might be the name of a place in County Dublin or the City of Dublin.

This is the 1851 Census of Machen, Monmouthshire, Wales (see HO 107/2453, folio 527, page 23).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it simply says 'British', indicating his nationality. Note that in 1851, Ireland was still part of the [United Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_of_Great_Britain_and_Ireland).

---

**Added in response to the comments:** It certainly was not necessary for the nationality to be included, but it is not clear whether this was added by the enumerator or the householder when he filled in the household schedule. The instructions on the [1851 household schedule](http://www.histpop.org/ohpr/servlet/PageBrowser?path=Browse/Census%20%28by%20date%29/1851&active=yes&mno=25&tocstate=expandnew&display=sections&display=tables&display=pagetitles&pageseq=5&zoom=4) could be easily mistaken to mean that British Subject should be written after the birthplace of someone born in Ireland:

> WHERE BORN.
>
> Opposite the Names of those born in England, write the
> *County*, and *Town* or *Parish*.
>
> If born in Scotland, Ireland, the British Colonies, the East Indies, or in Foreign Parts, state the
> *Country*; in the last case, if a British Subject, add, "*British Subject*."

Comment: Problem is that until the end of 1948, all Irish citizens were regarded as British subjects under English common law. So the question arises why this enumerator would feel the need to write "British" at all? Normally it was written in the context of people born in foreign countries. Perhaps he got confused about the rules....

Comment: Thank you both for your input. I thought it might be British as well, but I looked through the 1851 census for the entire parish of Machen and the census taker never wrote in British on any of the others that were born in Ireland. In fact, in all other instances, the census taker wrote in just Ireland, Ireland and the county, or Ireland, the county, and the town. It is certainly possible that it is British, but it doesn't seem to mesh with the pattern of the census taker.

Comment: @JoeMitchell The census enumerator may just have faithfully copied what was written on the household schedule. It is certainly true that it was not necessary to write that he was British subject.

Comment: @user3310902 I have added to my answer a possible source of the confusion